# Ruby prime_division returning two values,

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to return the divisors of the input and have come up with the below:

```
require 'prime'

def divisors(n)
  n.prime_division
end
```

With an input of 15, it is returning this:

```
Expected: [3, 5], instead got: [[3, 1], [5, 1]]
```

How do I make it return just 3 & 5 without the 1's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
15.prime_division.map(&:first) # => [3, 5]
```

The `1`s in the result stand for the number of occurrences (aka one 3 and one 5).

Comment: Precisely. In other words, if you want just the first value of each array, call `first` on each one.

Comment: This worked for two of the tests however for the third test (when the input is 24) its returning Expected: [2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12], instead got: [2, 3], any help?